# using a local_manifest.xml with repo

Tags: android, android-manifest, synchronization, repository

I downloaded the android sources using repo. It says repo is initialized to a directory and thats where the folders get downloaded. Now I have another local_manifest.xml file which I want to use with repo sync to fetch another directory. How do I use this new manifest file to fetch the directories to my repository?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do this:

```
cp your_local_mainifest.xml .repo/manifests
repo init -m your_local_manifest.xml
repo sync
```

Comment: sorry for the confused format.cp your_local_mainifest.xml .repo/manifests ;

Comment: This approach will delete all downloaded stuff from previous init and sync if such projects are missed in new manifest.

Comment: This not work for me. `fatal: manifest url (-u) is required.`

Answer (score 33):

Repo 1.9.1 has a new feature.

You'll find a new folder under `.repo/` named `local_manifests`.

The `repo` tool will follow also the projects in the manifest files you'll add into this folder.

More info [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20161225091938/https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_Using_local_manifests).

Comment: Are you sure you meant version 1.19? There is no such version at https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo, and the current version at the time you answered was more like 1.12.1.

Comment: The correct version is 1.9.1 which was [committed May 24, 2012](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/23acdd3f1460bc1c040b319940c5e0e8a78f1040)

Comment: This not work for me. `error: command 'sync' requires repo to be installed first.`

Comment: With archive.org link. Awesome, thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

If the file name is really `local_manifest.xml`, you most probably want to **add** it to your build instead of building using just it.  If that is the case, then simply place it in .repo:

```
  cp /whereever/local_manifest.xml .repo/local_manifest.xml
  repo sync
```

The `repo` tool essentially concatenates `manifest.xml` and `local_manifest.xml`.

For more information, see http://www.androidenea.com/2010/06/using-localmanifestxml-file-in-repo-to.html

Comment: I am used to push `local_manifest.xml` to `.repo/` folder, as you stated. What's the difference with hopliu' answer of pushing it to `.repo/manifests` ?

Comment: hopliu's answer shows how you build a whole Android with a local version of the manifest.xml file.  My version shows how you add more repositories to an existing Android build.  However, you should not use plain ``local_manifest.xml`` files any more, but use multiple several files as pointed out by lucabelluccini.

Comment: should put local manifest_name.xml to .repo/local_manifests directory if using new repo.