# repo using local manifest does not work

Tags: android, repository

Refference to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672394/using-a-local-manifest-xml-with-repo). 
I copy the `manifest.xml` to `.repo` and type:

```
repo init -m ./.repo/manifest.xml
```

And it does not work:

```
jack $ repo init -m ./.repo/manifest.xml 
fatal: manifest url (-u) is required.
```

I do provide manifest.xml. What is wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [init command documentation](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#init) - you are required to provide the URL to the repository.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I did to make this work locally.

I moved manifest.xml to a separate location like `~/mymanifest/manifest.xml`

I made that directory git-enabled by doing

```
cd ~/mymanifest
git init
git add manifest.xml
git commit -m "My local manifest"
```

Then I simply had to do `repo init -u ~/mymanifest/` which worked in loading up the local manifest like it should!

Answer (score 3):

I've never used that method. What I do in a situation like this is to create a file named `local_manifest.xml` in the `.repo` directory which contains information about the projects that will deviate from the branch I've already synced. For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <manifest>
   <remove-project name="platform/bionic"/>
   <project path="bionic"
        name="platform/bionic"
        revision="my-awesome-feature-branch"/>
 </manifest>
```

After adding this file I simply `repo sync` again.

Comment: I don't think this works for the first init. There is no .repo dir.

Answer (score 1):

proper way to use local manifest is similar to the Irfan answer but there is one correction:

```
cd ~/mymanifest
git init
git add manifest.xml
git commit -m "My local manifest"
```

then call repo providing both **url** and **file** flags:

```
repo init -u ~/mymanifest/ -m manifest.xml
```