# Can I extract multiple directories using local_manifest.xml from single repo?

Tags: android, git, synchronization, android-manifest, repo

I looked [this](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/docs/manifest-format.md#local-manifests) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672394/using-a-local-manifest-xml-with-repo) but my question looks little different.

We've vendor provided embedded platform running Android 10. We want to create a separate repository on our local bitbucket server for following 3 directories,

1. external
2. kernel
3. vendor

I've created `local_manifests/local_manifest.xml` and updated it with new `project` and `remove-project` tags accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
   <remote name="bitbucket" fetch="URL" revision="mybranch"/>
   <default remote="bitbucket" revision="mybranch"/>
   <project name="device-kernel" path="kernel" revision="mybranch"/>
   <project name="device-external" path="external" revision="mybranch"/>
   <project name="device-vendor" path="vendor" revision="mybranch"/>
   <remove-project name="kernel/build"/>
   <remove-project name="kernel/configs"/>
   <remove-project name="kernel/kernel-5.10"/>
   <remove-project name="kernel/tests"/>
   ...
</manifest>
```

It looks like I need to have 3 git repositories to have them extracted into 3 different directories. e.g. device-kernel will store kernel and can be exported inside kernel directory using the `path` attribute.

**Question:** Can just create one repository and store 3 directories in it instead of 3 repos? If yes, then how?
What I expect is with one repo it should export 3 directories in the same directory parallel to each other.

I would appreciate if your response has some reference xml or any reference article for same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Yes, In your case you can create one git repository and store your 3 directories in it. When `repo sync` is performed all 3 will be exported in the same directory.

If you read carefully the 1st link, you can actually put `path="."` in your project tag to achieve above. It is ignored for local manifests. Notice following,

> “path” may not be an absolute path or use “.” or “..” path components.
> These restrictions are not enforced for Local Manifests.

one more thing, your `local_manifest.xml` is missing the `remote` attribute in `project` tag though.