# How to clone/ropo sync code from specific buildID

Tags: clone, android-source, repo

I am trying to clone the AOSP source code and the build ID is "9407610".
I now only build ID. Is it possible to clone the source or repo sync from the build ID?

I have seen some blogs, that are saying sync code from through tag and build ID. But I don't know the tag name of this build.

I tried like below:

Step 1:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

Step 2: Downloaded manifest_9407610.xml file from [this link](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/9407610/aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug/latest) & replace content from manifest_9407610.xml to .repo/manifests/default.xml.

Step 3:

```
repo sync -c -j8
```

After a few hours I got below error:

> error: unable to read sha1 file of kernel-5.4-lz4
> (0833eee0dbc0dc81a8a410c34760a15617b142a3)
>
> error: unable to read sha1 file of kernel-5.4-lz4-allsyms
> (f7b760b37e01fec4ba1a976c32d3e533b96cfc2e)
>
> error: unable to read sha1 file of prebuilt-info.txt
> (9421e754bf0ca222620a4643f02481a6d32cc761)

I just tried this way, but it is not able to sync the complete code base.
Could you please suggest to me which is the proper way to clone and repo sync the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried below steps :

cp your_local_mainifest.xml .repo/manifests

repo init -m your_local_manifest.xml

repo sync

Ref link : [using a local_manifest.xml with repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672394/using-a-local-manifest-xml-with-repo)